# Virtualbox VDE Network

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-network

i am programming a GUI-Tool to test some Meshnetworkingthings.

To do so i use Virtualbox, VDE2 and Wirefilter. My attempt is to generate *n* openwrt instances with Virtualbox, connect them with vde_switch in tap mode and simulate pocketloss etc. with wirefilter.

Here's what im trying to this point:

```
sudo ip tuntap add tap<i> mode tap
sudo ifconfig tap<i> <some ip> up
vde_switch -d -x -s /tmp/tap<i>/ -m 666
VBoxManage clonevm openwrt --name tap<i> --register
VBoxManage modifyvm tap<i> --nic1 generic --nicgenericdrv1 VDE --nicproperty1 network=/tmp/tap<i>/ --macaddress1 <mac>
VBoxManage startvm tap<i>
```

But i get the following error when i try to run a openwork instance:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine tap.

VDEplug library: not found (VERR_PDM_HIF_OPEN_FAILED).

Failed to attach the network LUN (VERR_PDM_HIF_OPEN_FAILED).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: Console
Interface: IConsole {8ab7c520-2442-4b66-8d74-4ff1e195d2b6}
```

Development Environment:
I am using a MacBook Pro, where Ubuntu 14.04 runs in Virtualbox. In this Ubuntu i am developing my tool. That means i am running Virtualbox in Virtualbox.

Answer (score 1):

I Solved it. First what to do:

copy libvdeplug.so.2 to libvdeplug.so

```
cp /usr/lib/libvdeplug.so.2 /usr/lib/libvdeplug.so
```

Then i forgot something in the vde_switch call:

```
vde_switch -d -x -s /tmp/tap<i>/ -m 666
```

has to be

```
vde_switch -d -x -s /tmp/tap<i>/ -m 666 --tap tap<i>
```